# saving a pdf to the filesystem

Tags: iphone

How can i save a pdf from a url using NSData in my iphone resources, and then call those up after every app launch to load.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking your question in three parts:

**Downloading**

In terms of downloading the PDF, the easiest means is via the [NSString](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)  `stringWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error:` method (and other related methods in NSString) and the [NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class, which is capable of performing asynchronous background requests.

Both of the above linked class reference documents contain code samples (see the "Related sample code" section at the top of each). Additionally, there are 3rd party solutions available, such as the commonly used [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) class.

**Saving**

Once you have the relevant NSData or NSString object, you can simply save it to a file within your apps document directory using NSData `writeToFile:options:error:` method or the NSString `writeToFile:atomically:encoding:error:`method, after getting the relevant base path via the `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains` foundation function as follows:

```
NSArray *searchPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentPath = [searchPaths objectAtIndex:0];
```

**Displaying**

In terms of displaying the resultant PDF, you'll need to check out the [CGPDFDocument Reference docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPDFDocument/Reference/reference.html), although there are thankfully a few [online](http://iosguy.com/2010/09/04/presenting-pdf-files-by-yourself/) [examples](http://www.veltema.jp/blog/2010/6/displaying-pdf-documents-on-ios-) that should help to illustrate how you can harness this class to display the PDF file.